# Is there any sense or organisation to the Umbraco .Net namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, umbraco

Umbraco has a variety of namespaces, however, they seem ill-organised and complicated.

For instance, what's the difference between

```
umbraco.businesslogic
```

and

```
umbraco.cms.businesslogic
```

Is there anything behind the way they're organised?

Comment: To me `umbraco.businesslogic` does not seem like a good namespace name. It is very broad. I personally like Microsoft's guidelines (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx): <Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]

Comment: Yeah you mean like "system.web.extensions"? what the hell does that do (by just looking at the namespace name). And Entity Framework in "System.Data.Entity" when really it should be "Microsoft.EntityFramework"?... The scheme they come up makes sense. Only problem is they rn't following it themselves. (No really. Since when is EF part of System?!?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head,

umbraco.businesslogic = business logic for the whole application

while

umbraco.cms.businesslogic = business logic powering the umbraco backend admin section, acting like a facade to the umbraco.businesslogic with authorization, etc thrown in.

When you think about it, it makes sense because of how much more complicated the administration section is, compared to the actual site the application present (Just a url rewrite lookup against the xml/db and combining a bunch of xslt/controls/masterpages/contents/etc).

Comment: Well, I'll accept this, as I'm not surprised I haven't received any other answers.  Thanks for the answer!  Frankly, although this specific answer is ok, it doesn't include the other namespaces and Umbraco is a terrible mess overall.

Comment: Haha, gotta agree with you on that one. Hope it'll be better with v5 rebuild. (taking so long ... zzz )

Comment: Yeah, that was beyond shocking.